# Improving a Spreadsheet Formula to be more dynamic

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a a couple sheets that I want to filter the values of and sum them together. I have a working function:

```
=SUM(INDEX(Grades!M32:V32,0,B2)+INDEX(Grades!M32:V32,0,C2)+INDEX(Grades!M32:V32,0,D2)+INDEX(Grades!M32:V32,0,E2)+INDEX(Grades!M32:V32,0,F2)+INDEX(Grades!M32:V32,0,G2))
```

and this is working fine. The problem is it isn't really dynamic and I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to approach this instead of using so many Indexes.

Index is grabbing a horizontal range of numbers from another sheet and getting the needed index position from a small table in another sheet.

## Update

I was able to get the formula working how I wanted by inserting an `IF` statement that would not do the `VLOOKUP` if one of the cells was empty.

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(IF(B2:I2 <> "",VLOOKUP(1,{1,Grades!$M$32:$V$32},B2:I2+1))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks a bit strange, but this is one way:

`=ArrayFormula(SUM(VLOOKUP(1,{1,Grades!M32:V32},B2:G2+1,0)))`

---

In the `VLOOKUP`, `1` is the value you are searching for, `{1,Grades!M32:V32}` is the array in which you are searching, `B2:G2+1` is the column index (or rather, indices) you wish to return, and `0` dictates that you require an exact match.

`{1,Grades!M32:V32}` constructs a horizontal, one-row array that has `1` in the left-most element, with the values in `Grades!M32:V32` to the right of it.

`VLOOKUP` will search down the left-most column of that array. It will always "find" the `1` that it is searching for in the left-most column, because we have purposely manufactured that.

Where the action really happens is in the third argument, where we return the columns in that manufactured array corresponding with the values in `B2:G2` (I should add, I assumed that all cells in `B2:G2` are populated - it will return the wrong result if any are blank). The `+1` is to account for the extra element (the `1`) we tacked on to the left of the lookup array.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the answer. It looks like it could potentially be the direction I am looking for. It is unfortunately returning the wrong sum result. Can walk me through what it is that is happening in the VLOOKUP? Why is the search key 1, what type of range is {1,Grades!M32:V32},B2:G2+1, and is 0 then the index ? It would be great if you could step this out for me a bit. Thanks!

Comment: After playing around a bit I managed to get the correct answer returned. '=ArrayFormula(SUM(VLOOKUP(1,{0,B11:K11},B2:G2+1)))' Still not sure why it is working. Look forwarded to a walk through if you could!

Comment: Post edited. Not quite sure why it didn't work. Do all the cells in B2:G2 have a value in them?

Comment: Was able to do a workaround (see edit). Strange this was that if a cell was empty or even 0 it seemed to increment the final sum by per empty/0 row. Thanks again for your help!